# Request cannot be routed while deploying to SAPUI5 ABAP Repository

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-web-ide, abap-adt

When I try to deploy an application from WEBIDE to an internal System, it is throwing an error:

> "Request cannot be routed. The server has not found any Matching resource /sap/bc/adt/discovery".

The service /sap/bc/adt is active in SICF, cloud connector and Destinations have been configured Correctly.

[image: DEPLOY TO SAPUI5 ABAP REPOSITYRY]
[image: DESTINATION CONFIGURATION]

Answer (score 0):

make sure the values in the property WebIDEUsage in the destination are correct (first a in dev_abap looks strange).

Here you have all the possible values and the explanation 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/Cloud/en-US/5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html

> dev_abap: for extensibility scenarios and developing or deploying to
>   SAPUI5 ABAP Repository (corresponds to URL path /sap/bc/adt)

Comment: thats not the issue, the error message says "cannot find service" - which means the call is passed to the backend, and the respecitve ICF service is not active or available...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely some services are not activated in SICF, you should check them in detail.